# create user defined methods that access objects of oncreate()

Tags: android, methods, oncreate

i am trying to develop an application where i have a set of code that has to be called each time a button is out of 5 button is pressed. only the id of the file to be opened associated with it changes
so i need to create a method that can access all the objects created in the onCreate() like buttons etc.

```
public class Aero extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.aero);
    final SlidingDrawer slider = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer1);
    final TextView secondyear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ae2yrsyll);
    final ScrollView scrl = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ae_three_sem_am3);
    Button two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ae_three_sem_at);
    Button three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ae_three_sem_fmm);
    Button four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ae_three_sem_cp);
    Button five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ae_three_sem_ea);
    one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void mymethod(int resourse) {
            scrl.pageScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(resourse);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            String entireFile = "";
            try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // <--------- place
                                                            // readLine()
                                                            // inside loop
                    entireFile += (line + "\n"); // <---------- add each
                                                    // line to entireFile
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            secondyear.setText(entireFile); // <------- assign entireFile to
                                            // TextView
            if (slider.isOpened()) {
                slider.close();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            scrl.pageScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.aero1);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            String entireFile = "";
            try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // <--------- place
                                                            // readLine()
                                                            // inside loop
                    entireFile += (line + "\n"); // <---------- add each
                                                    // line to entireFile
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            secondyear.setText(entireFile); // <------- assign entireFile to
                                            // TextView
            if (slider.isOpened()) {
                slider.close();
            }
        }
    });

    two.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            scrl.pageScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.aero2);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            String entireFile = "";
            try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // <--------- place
                                                            // readLine()
                                                            // inside loop
                    entireFile += (line + "\n"); // <---------- add each
                                                    // line to entireFile
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            secondyear.setText(entireFile); // <------- assign entireFile to
                                            // TextView
            if (slider.isOpened()) {
                slider.close();
            }
        }
    });
    three.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            scrl.pageScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.aero3);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            String entireFile = "";
            try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // <--------- place
                                                            // readLine()
                                                            // inside loop
                    entireFile += (line + "\n"); // <---------- add each
                                                    // line to entireFile
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            secondyear.setText(entireFile); // <------- assign entireFile to
                                            // TextView
            if (slider.isOpened()) {
                slider.close();
            }
        }
    });
    four.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            scrl.pageScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.aero4);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            String entireFile = "";
            try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // <--------- place
                                                            // readLine()
                                                            // inside loop
                    entireFile += (line + "\n"); // <---------- add each
                                                    // line to entireFile
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            secondyear.setText(entireFile); // <------- assign entireFile to
                                            // TextView
            if (slider.isOpened()) {
                slider.close();
            }
        }
    });
    five.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            scrl.pageScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.aero5);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            String entireFile = "";
            try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // <--------- place
                                                            // readLine()
                                                            // inside loop
                    entireFile += (line + "\n"); // <---------- add each
                                                    // line to entireFile
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            secondyear.setText(entireFile); // <------- assign entireFile to
                                            // TextView
            if (slider.isOpened()) {
                slider.close();
            }
        }
    });
```

therfore i want to create a method called myMethod which would be like below

```
myMethod(int reso){scrl.pageScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(reso);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            String entireFile = "";
            try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // <--------- place
                                                            // readLine()
                                                            // inside loop
                    entireFile += (line + "\n"); // <---------- add each
                                                    // line to entireFile
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            secondyear.setText(entireFile); // <------- assign entireFile to
                                            // TextView
            if (slider.isOpened()) {
                slider.close();
            }}
```

where do i place this method?
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save your Views into Variables in the Activity and access them.

```
public class Aero extends Activity {

    TextView mSecondYear;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.aero);
        mSecondYear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ae2yrsyll);
        ...
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        mSecondYear.setText("bla");
    }
}
```